# I have some questions about the child nodes of the text nodes of XML DOM

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

As far as i know , text nodes(nodeType==3) have no child nodes,but---
Here is a text node , which nodeName is Course,under normal circumstances,it has no child nodes,however,it seems the text node has 8 childnodes , and all the childnodes are undefined.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUjup.png)

Comment: <Course>CS Basis</Course>

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what a text node is. Please refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) or another source of your choice to find out what it is.

Comment: Please show all relevant code in the question itself. See [mcve]

Comment: XML code:<Course>CS Basis</Course>  DOM:x=xmlDoc.documentElement;y=x.getElementsByTagName("Course");      result : y.item(0).childNodes[0].length = 8